# DirectoryEntry and Powershell shows different result

Tags: c#, windows, active-directory, ldap

When I apply the filter :

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(xxx@xxxxx.com))
```

On Powershell and using DirectoryEntry in c# I get different results

I run this on Powershell :

Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(xxx@xxxxx.com))"

Why does this happend? Does it has to do with the user?

Comment: Where is the code? what is the AD topology? Powershell may do referral chasing for you, have a different base DN (root DSE) specified among other things...

Comment: Or it could be subject to access controls, i.e you are not authenticating as the same user.

Comment: How is this `xxx@xxxxx.com` a filter condition in itself? Would you please share your exact code.

Answer (score 0):

First, note that in the example you provided the filter has an invalid syntax. The 3rd part - (xxx@xxxxx.com) - is not a valid filter expression. I assume you wanted something like (userprincipalname=xxx@xxxxx.com).

The difference between Get-ADUser and DirectoryEntry is most likely due to the fact that Get-ADUser adds extra filtering as its semantics implies. If you want to have an equal behavior consider using Get-ADObject and make sure that the base DN and search scope parameters are the same.

Comment: *The difference between Get-ADUser and DirectoryEntry is most likely due to the fact that Get-ADUser adds extra filtering as its semantics implies...* - I believe all the filters can be applied using DirectoryServices/DirectoryEntry too.